# Directory appearing as file, acting like directory in bash

Tags: files, filesystem, directory, chmod

This question has been asked before, but, I think without the appropriate complete description of the problem so it was dismissed off-hand, but it's real, and I'm looking at it.  This is not my first time at the linux rodeo (though I'm certainly not as experienced as many on this site).

```
$ls -l
... (some directories, some folders)
-rw-r--r--  1 ben ben 70646656 Jun 22 10:44 _images
... (other directories, some folders)
$rm _images
rm: cannot remove '_images': Is a directory
$cd _images 
# works like directory
$ls _images*
# lists contents of _images and other directories matching the pattern.
```

The directory appears as a file in "Atom" and, as noted previously, when using the ls command.  I feel like I should do something to fix this but have no idea what.
Cheers friends.

Comment: The question is unclear. Directories and folders is the same thing.

Comment: Please post the whole output of the first `ls -l`.

Comment: Also add the output of `stat _images`

Comment: @Pilot6 Ackshually, [directories and folders are not exactly the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191381/english-ui-terminology-directory-or-folder/1195096#1195096).  Although, I think the use of folders is [limited to Windows systems dating back to win95 and newer](https://superuser.com/questions/169457/directory-vs-folder).

Comment: Which version of **Ubuntu** and which version of **`bash`** and **`ls`** are you running? And what **file system** is it? Can you check if there is some kind of corruption in the file system (and hopefully fix it, if you find something fishy)?

Comment: Will you please link to the other question or answers that fail to explain the problem? I think it would help us understand what additional information needs to be explained.

Comment: please add the results of `file _images`. and also what filesystem this is on. and if ext a filesystem checks fixes this.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind in such situation is the possibility of `_images` being actually a file that is hard linked to a directory … This is, however, seems to not be allowed anymore on newer releases of Ubuntu with newer versions of `ln` … but, possible nonetheless … you, however, haven’t provided enough supporting information for us to tell for sure … So, this is merely  an educated guess.

Comment: Vanilla, stock install of Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS. No component updates outside of stock Ubuntu updates.  Rest of directory includes other directories and hundreds of files.  Those all have the appropriate file attributes as to indicate a directory and not merely a file.